# RecyclerView onClick

Tags: recyclerview

Hello dear programmers!

Perhaps for someone this question is considered really easy, but I have been fighting this question for 2 weeks. How is clicking on the TextView so that there is a transition to the site, or at least in which direction to go. Clicking occurs, but the transition to clicking is not and that's it. in recyclerview

I will be glad for any help

[image: circled in red]

Comment: Alex, переведите ваш вопрос на русский. Возможно, вы перепутали русский stack overflow и английский

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте к TextView свойство:

```
android:autoLink="web"
```